# Are hints rather than full answers for educating beginners allowed?

Tags: discussion, answers, stack-exchange

Sometimes I see beginners in a subject (it is apparent in the question) asking for solving some issue. My natural instinct is to guide them to resolving the problem themselves rather that just giving the answer. I think it is better education to learn how to solve the problem in general than get a quick answer.

However I do not think this is really *correct* for Stack Exchange. What is the best way to proceed for such examples?

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly my question but I couldn't find it with search. Is it ok to take the accepted answer as 'true'? The person asking the question marked it as accepted but there's other answers that disagree.

Comment: This is site specific. Hints are allowed on [the Math site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22266). (Actually, that site may be the only one where hints are considered answers; I can't think of another site right now with a policy like that.)